# Ленивые квантификаторы, флаг glob и метод replace  - это возможно?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Сегодня понял, что выбирать текст при помощи replace, хоть на чуть-чуть, но быстрее.
И теперь целый день мучаюсь и не могу сделать то, что под exec уже сделал. Вот строка -

```
var str = 'DDDDDDDDDDD\n/**\n * 111\n * 222\n */\nXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n\nEEEEEEEEEEE\n/**\n * 333\n * 444\n */';
```

Это строка jsDoc, и нужно выбрать только строки с комментами -

> - 111\n
> - 222\n
> - 333\n
> - 444\n

При помощи регулярного выражения для метода exec у меня получился массив со следующими строками -

> [ ' * 111\n', ' * 222\n', ' * 333\n',
> ' * 444\n' ]

```
var str = 'DDDDDDDDDDD\n/**\n * 111\n * 222\n */\nXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n\nEEEEEEEEEEE\n/**\n * 333\n * 444\n */';
var re = /(^|\n)\/\*\*\n([\s\S]+?) \*\/(?=\n|$)/g;

var source = [];
var cut = [];
var result =[];
var cutLength = NaN;
var row = null;
var item = null;
var DESIRED_ITEM = 2;

var ERROR_COUNT = 0;
var CHARACTER_OF_NEXT_LINE = '\n';

while((source = re.exec(str)) != null){
    row = source[DESIRED_ITEM];
    cut = row.split('\n');
    cutLength = cut.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < cutLength; i++){
        item = cut[i];

        if (item != '') {
            result.push(item + CHARACTER_OF_NEXT_LINE);
        };
    }
}
console.log(result)
```

Кода много, регулярка монстрическая, но только при помощи неё я смог застраховаться от символов, обозначающих jsDoc в самих комментах.

Вот... Но вопрос в другом, помогите понять, как сделать то же самое, но при помощи replace?
Я начал и сразу наткнулся на проблему ленивого квантификатора для выборки \n и флага glob.

```
var str = 'DDDDDDDDDDD\n/**\n * 111\n * 222\n */\nXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n\nEEEEEEEEEEE\n/**\n * 333\n * 444\n */';
var re = /(^|\n)?/g

console.log(str.replace(re, ''));
```

Как видно, я сразу же удаляю все переносы строк \n и, как это решить, не знаю. Тут нужно сделать ленивость, но она как будто не работает с глобал. Что посоветуете? Может, кто-то сможет показать решение? Я был бы очень рад)))

Comment: replace одну строку "выбирает", т.е. заменяет ее на другую. Может, Вам подойдет .match() ?

Comment: Интересно, а Вы пишете зачем-то парсер jsDoc? Зачем?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2t3wfpzh/2/, нет, не сломается, из-за ленивого кватификатора, как я понимаю.

>  А подгонять себя под чей-то код я не хочу, лучше сделать самому.

Не лучше абсолютно ничем.

Comment: Когда оптимизируете по скорости,  надо мерять не скорость выполнения, а относительную разницу методов. Мало того, могут быть разные движки, например, вы решили сравнить, что быстрее - `256/2` или `256 >> 1`, делается это так - запускаем миллион раз одно и другое и делим одно на другое, по идее, на одинаковом движке цифры будут похожими (на самом деле там еще оптимизатор можно поотключать и прочее).

Comment: Я вот как меряю http://jsfiddle.net/xo3w0o5z/ . Вот если меряю на nodejs, то exec быстрее match в два раза, а если в браузере, то в семь. При чем exec по скорости и на nodejs, и в браузере одинаков. Но опять, сижу в ubuntu, и интерпритаторы ubuntu браузеров могут отличаться от других.

Comment: И ещё, как я понял, разные методы по разному ведут себя при разном объеме текста. Exec побеждает на маленьком объеме match, даже если требуется цикл и сохранение результатов в другой массив, но проигрывает при увелечении объема текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример с match

```
var str = 'DDDDDDDDDDD\n/**\n * 111\n * 222\n */\nXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n\nEEEEEEEEEEE\n/**\n * 333\n * 444\n */';
var re=/\/\*[.\s\S]*?\*\//g;
console.log(str.match(re));
```

на выходе массив с комментами,

Comment: И мне нужно [ ' * 111\n', ' * 222\n', ' * 333\n', ' * 444\n' ], но это не относится к вопросу. Спасибо Вам! Регулярки, наверное, никто не любит :) Я упертый, буду пытаться дальше.

Comment: @vas, я их люблю, и в них нет абсолютно ничего трудного. Просто надо внимательно прочитать нормальную книгу по ним :-)

Comment: Я люблю регулярки, ими удобно парсить текст, логи всякие и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов

```
var str = 'DDDDDDDDDDD\n/**\n * 111\n * 222\n */\nXXXXXXXXXXX\n\n\nEEEEEEEEEEE\n/**\n * 333\n * 444\n */';
var re = /\/\*\*\n([\s\S]+?)\*\//g
var result = [];
str.replace(re, function ($0, $1) {
    result.push.apply(result, $1.match(/.*\n/g));
});
console.log(result)
```